# ¿Por qué dicen "la patria es primero" y no "primera"?

Tags: género

¿Por qué dicen

> La patria es **primero**

y no

> La patria es **primera**

También, por ejemplo,

> La panza es **primero**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Primero" en oraciones como:

- La patria es primero.
- La panza es primero.

proviene de:

- La patria es lo primero.
- La panza es lo primero.

donde "lo primero" es una frase sustantiva en la que "primero" es un adjetivo con artículo neutro ("lo primero" = la primera cosa, la cosa más importante).

También se podría decir: *lo principal*.

Se usa el masculino porque el neutro "lo" requiere masculino.

También puede decirse:

- La patria viene primero.
- La panza viene primero.

donde "primero" es adverbio, equivalente a "en primer lugar".